# Inserir virgula após verificar mais de um nome

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    var strTypesModel = "";
    foreach (var typesModel in user.typesModel)
    {
        strTypesModel = strTypesModel + typesModel.Name;
    }

    user.TypesModelAggregate = strTypesModel;
}
```

Quero inserir uma virgula,caso tenha mais nomes cadastrado.

Comment: user.TypesModelAggregate = string.Join(",", user.typesModel);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta fazer um `string.Join`:

```
foreach (var user in users)
    user.TypesModelAggregate = string.Join(",", user.typesModel.Name);
```

Desta forma a concatenação é efetuada por cada elemento.

Comment: De nada, estamos aqui para isso! Dê um UP na resposta e marque-a como válida se o realmente o ajudou!

Comment: Obrigado João pelo apoio! Dessa maneira não foi possível realizar a inserção separados por vírgulas,nesse caso tenho um combobox com multiselect,que ao selecionar mais de um valor,separá-los por vírgula quando imprimir o novo cadastro na tabela de usuários..

Comment: Então se calhar é melhor detalhar mais a sua questão, senão as respostas não vão estar de acordo com o que precisa.

Comment: Coloquei o código do meu method Get para melhor entendimento!

Answer (score 0):

No caso eu tenho um multiselect no html,e quero separar os valores selecionados dentro do combobox e separar por vírgulas na hora que eu listar todos usuários com seus respctivos tipos de solicitações.

```
  public IEnumerable<UserDataModel> Get()
    {
        UserDataModel userModel = new UserDataModel();
        //var reg = ctx.User.Include(x => x.Area.Name).Include(x =>x.RequestType);


        var users = ctx.User.OrderBy(u => u.Name).Select(u => new 
                        UserDataModel
        {
            typesModel = u.RequestType.Select(x => new RequestTypeModel
            {
                Id = x.IdRequestType,
                Name = x.Name
            }).ToList()


        }).ToList();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var strTypesModel = "";
            foreach (var typesModel in user.typesModel)
            {
                strTypesModel = strTypesModel + typesModel.Name;

                user.TypesModelAggregate = string.Join(",", user.typesModel);
            }

        }
     return users;
    }
```